# C# Enumerable Range

Tags: c#

What is the way to get Range "A"..."Z" like

```
Enumerable.Range(1,100) 

Enumerable.Range("A","Z");
```

Comment: I think you should use 'A', 'Z'. chars instead of strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => ((char)x).ToString())
```

Comment: Why the call to `ToString` out of interest? I wouldn't expect that to do anything useful...

Comment: Because otherwise when you start enumerating you will get integers/chars (65, 66, ...) instead of strings ("A", "B", ...) which would be more practical.

Comment: Another possibility is to call `ToString()` during the enumeration but I thought the returning `IEnumerable<string>` would be easier.

Comment: @Darin: Ah, had missed the relevant brackets - thought you were calling ToString on the IEnumerable returned :)

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Updated to include Darin's correction...

In .NET 3.5 SP1, this would have worked:

```
Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Cast<char>()
```

However, the behaviour of `Cast` [changed for .NET 3.5 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx), so it now only performs reference conversions on unboxing conversions. So for .NET 3.5SP1 and above, you need:

```
Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => (char) x);
```

It's not terribly nice, admittedly.

With [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) you could use

```
'A'.To('Z').StepChar(1)
```

Whether you like that or not is a matter of personal taste :)

Comment: @Jon, `Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Cast<char>().ToArray()` will throw an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Thanks Jon.Just I am studying Chapter 11 (Query Expression and Linq to Objects) of your book.

Comment: I have one more doubt what is the difference between Of ofType<> and Cast<> ?

Comment: `OfType` will just not pass on anything it can't cope with; Cast will throw an exception. However, Darin's right - the behaviour of Cast changed for .NET 3.5SP1.

Answer (score 12):

Why not just keep it simple...

```
public static IEnumerable<char> GetAlphabet()
{
    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".AsEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, if you want to slice from one element of the alphabet to another...

```
Enumerable.Range(0,26).Select(x => (char)((char)x + 'A'))
```