# how to get numbers from a string and store it in a variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a value like this `ab48/2012`. How to extract the numbers from this string? I need to store `48` in one variable and `2012` in another variable.

Is it possible to extract numbers without using the substring function?
If it is possible, please help me.

I have tried like this

```
string Value = "ab48/2012";
string[] array = value.Split('/');
int Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(array[0].Substring(2));
int Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(array[1].ToString());
```

Comment: Are all strings of the same format?

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: What happened when you tried ?

Comment: Can the numbers be negative and/or have decimal places?

Comment: `Is it possible to extract numbers without using the substring function?`. Yes it is. But why would you change your code that is working? What do you think your code is wrong?

Comment: I dont want to hardcode it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] parts = "abc48/2012".Split('/');
int value1 = Int32.Parse(new String(parts[0].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
int value2 = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
```

If you find yourself using this sort of code a lot you could introduce a utility extension method e.g.

```
public static string GetIntegersOnly(this string str)
{
    return new String(str.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
}
...
int value1 = Int32.Parse(parts[0].GetIntegersOnly())
```

Comment: I love literals with `.Anything`. It a shame, and clear, you lack votes because your answer lacks Regex. `++votes;`

Comment: @C.Lang yeah, I personally try to use the Framework as much as possible before Regex, they can be complicated at the best of times. Oh, You would love this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741870/c-sharp-enumerable-range/1741956#1741956) then!

Comment: Yep, with diversity comes cleverness! Love that answer!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
int[] numbers = Regex.Split(Value, @"\D+")
                .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToArray();
```

NOTE: This does NOT handle negative numbers or numbers with decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "ab48/2012";
var regex = new Regex(@"^[^\d]*(?<a>\d*?)/(?<b>\d*)$");
var m = regex.Match(input);
if(m.Success)
{
    var a = m.Groups["a"].Value;
    var b = m.Groups["b"].Value;
    var aVal = int.Parse(a);
    var bVal = int.Parse(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression

```
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("abc48/2012", "[0-9]+", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach(var val in result){
                var temp_variable = val;
            }
```

Comment: I downvoted initially because your answer just said `You can use Regular Expression`. That wasn't an answer. Now that you've updated it with code and the regex, I've removed the downvote :)

Comment: I understood the mistake. Thx:)

Comment: Explain what the regex does.

Comment: Find all numbers from string into array 'result'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
string[] tokens = "ab48/2012".Split('/');
int num = int.Parse(new string(tokens.First().Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
int year = int.Parse(tokens.Last());
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/hsTeC6)

But in general i don't understand your reservations against `Substring` which is very efficient.

Comment: I assume the OP doesn't want to use `Substring` because it would a slightly more complicated piece of code if the digits aren't guaranteed to be together e.g. `ab4c35`.

Comment: @James: OP has showed just one sample and hasn't mentioned actual problems or limitations of `Substring`. That's why i have mentioned that there is nothing bad in using `Substring` or other string functions when the format of the input is strict. It's the most efficient and direct approach, even more efficient than using `Split` which produces unecessary arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
string value = "ab48/2012";
var charArray = value.ToCharArray().
           Reverse().TakeWhile(c=>char.IsDigit(c)).Reverse().ToArray();
var resultString = new string(charArray);
```

- create char array
- reverse it
- get all chars till first NOT digit
- reverse back
- pass to char array
- create a new string from that array

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var str = "ab48/2012";
            var strArr = string.Join("", str.Skip(2)).Split('/');
            Console.WriteLine(strArr[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(strArr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some Regex fu?

```
int value1, value2;
var match = Regex.Match(value, @"^[^\d]*(?<value1>[\d]+)/(?<value2>[\d]+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    value1 = int.Parse(match.Groups["value1"].Value);
    value2 = int.Parse(match.Groups["value2"].Value);
}
```